OKTA login on Android with SAML not authenticating
We are trying to implement okta login using SAML technique
We are using Android web view to load URL which contains OKTA JS script widget as below.
<script src="https://global.oktacdn.com/okta-signin-widget/7.23.1/js/okta-sign-in.min.js" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha384-iS0TwfhBrj8wuaNgQy6cYGrF3CF2JvvZXfMzVrk6BZ5yqtquDItZCLrhpN2YzX+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
<link href="https://global.oktacdn.com/okta-signin-widget/7.23.1/css/okta-sign-in.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4MFLFWndyGkfT8NgzmoJbWDD4YjzbMANE7ncx/sqPLBTkSqnrgFzjaQ0r8PewThU" crossorigin="anonymous" />

in our case client unable to Authenticate for Android Device getting the error/incomplete payload device details are missing. FYI, Client configured SSO with device trust, where the same implementation working in IOS.
Any help about what can be done, really appreciated.
Webview code is as below
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        webView.settings.allowFileAccess = true
        webView.settings.allowContentAccess = true
        CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null)
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(
            LoadListener(findNavController(), activity as BaseActivity),
            "androidClient"
        )
        setupWebClient()
        webView.clearCache(true)
        webView.loadUrl(url)

